# Falla al traer los datos a un formulario NODE.js

Tags: nodejs

bueno tengo un problema estoy haciendo el video de FaztWeb y tengo un error ya que la versión que usa de handlebarts es antigua y hay unas cosas que no entiendo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El usa esta funcion para traer los datos a un formulario de editar pero esto no funciona ya que la versión es antigua y ya no se traen los datos así de que manera puedo traer eso.
Mi codigo es así

El error que me da es: (node:3292) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: EditDocumentos.map is not a function

```
router.get('/notes/edit/:id', async (req,res) => {
await Note.findById(req.params.id)
.then(EditDocumentos => {
    const EditContexto = {
        Editnotes: EditDocumentos.map(EditDocumento => {
            return {
                title: EditDocumento.title,
                description: EditDocumento.description
            }
        })
    }
    res.render('notes/edit-note', {
        Editnotes: EditContexto.Editnotes
    })
})
```

})

Aqui esta el video por si no me hice entender https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-bI0diefasA&t=5319s
Minuto: 1:42:00

Comment: Según yo, lanforma en que aparece en el video aun es aceptada y tu problema no es el de handlebarts sino que tu variable `EditDocumentos` no es un array

Comment: Pues ya lo puse como el lo hace en el video y me sale este error:Access has been denied to resolve the property "_id" because it is not an "own property" of its parent.
You can add a runtime option to disable the check or this warning: https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime-options.html#options-to-control-prototype-access

Comment: Tu actual error se debe a algo con la consulta a mongodb, no soy experto en mongo por lo que no puedo ayudarte mucho